# Looking for matching names among two text files

Tags: javascript, performance, parsing, iteration

I'm trying to enhance the execution speed of my below code. I am using only vanilla JavaScript. I would be willing to bring in additional libraries and plugins as long as they will enhance the overall speed of the code.

The goal is to have the **absolute fastest execution time** of the below code.

Currently, it executes from start to finish in approx. 320 - 350 ms. I want to make any modifications necessary to make it perform faster than that, particularly with exponentially larger datasets.

**Setup**

- I have two `.txt` files, `names` and `data`.
- `names` contains a list of last names, one name per line:

  > ```
  > Nader
  > Sanford
  > Kovacek
  > Lynch
  > etc...
  > ```
- `data` contains a much longer list, of first names, last names, a comma and a value:

  > ```
  > Kailee Huel,2
  > Arianna Runolfsson,4
  > Marshall Kuhn,3
  > Cristina Huel,4
  > Garnett Medhurst,3
  > etc...
  > ```

**Task**

Iterate through `data.txt` using the last names in `names.txt`. If any of the last names from `names.txt` have a match in `data.txt`, increment a counter with the value on that line (after the comma). Some last names are repeated in both `names.txt` and `data.txt`. Output the final value of the counter.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var names,
  data;

    // doc rdy
    document.onreadystatechange = function(){
      console.time('execution length');
      if( document.readyState == "complete" ){
        init();
      }
    }

    // setup
    function init(){
      var base      = "data/sample2/",
          namesFile = base+"names.txt",
          dataFile  = base+"data.txt";

      loadFile(namesFile, function(e){
        names = e;
        loadFile(dataFile, function(ev){
          processData(ev);
        });
      });
    }


    function processData(e){
      var counter = 0;
      var namesProcessed = {};

      // for each last name,
      for( var i=0; i<names.length; i++ ){
        // if "data object" contains "this name" AND "this name" does not exist in rmvdNames, add its val to counter
        if( e.hasOwnProperty(names[i]) && ! namesProcessed.hasOwnProperty(names[i]) ){
          counter += e[names[i]];
          namesProcessed[names[i]] = true;
        }
      }
      console.log(counter);
      console.timeEnd('execution length');
    }


    // ajax loading
    function loadFile( filename, callback ){
      var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var result;
      client.open('GET', filename);
      client.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( client.readyState==4 && client.status==200 ){
          result = client.responseText.split("\n");
          // custom handling for the data set..
          if( result[0].search(',') !== -1 ){
            result = arrCSVtoObj(result);
          }

          callback(result);
        }
      }
      client.send();
    }


    // converts an array of CSV to a key:value object
    function arrCSVtoObj(csvArr) {
      var obj = {};

      // for each line in the array,
      for( var i=0; i<csvArr.length; i++ ){
        // split into key:value on comma
        var split = csvArr[i].split(",");
        var key =  getLastName(split[0]);
        var val = parseInt(split[1]);

        // assign the new property to the object
        if( ! obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ){
          if( val > 0 ){
            obj[key] = val;
          }
        }else{
          obj[key] += val;
        }
      }
      return obj;
    }

    function getLastName(e){
      var nameArr = e.split(" ");
      return nameArr[1];
    }

  </script>
```

I know the biggest time sink in this script are the loops (there are several: looping through object properties, looping through data to parse it, etc). How can I speed these actions up? What measures can I take to improve the above code and optimize absolute speed with large datasets?

Comment: Is this an exercise? Real people have multi part family names.

Comment: @konijn: yes it is just an exercise. It'd need to be more robust for cases like you stated. :)

Comment: Normally, in US, programs like this will add all last names to LAST_NAME, or else add all but the very last name to FIRST_NAME in cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that really jumped out at me is your `loadFile` method is using **synchronous http requests** (looks accidental as you're using a callback anyway, see [msdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) for why this should be avoided etc).

Instead of `client.open('GET', filename);` you probably want `client.open('GET', filename, true);`

Making async requests will allow the first notable improvement I would make is to make `init` loading async. I'm going to use the native promises -- feel free to adapt

```
// setup
function init() {
  var base = "data/sample2/",
    namesFile = base + "names.txt",
    dataFile = base + "data.txt";

  Promise.all([loadFile(namesFile), loadFile(dataFile)])
  .then(function(values) {
    var names = values[0];
    processData(values[1]);
  });
}

// ajax loading
function loadFile(filename) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, error) {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open('GET', filename, true);
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (client.readyState == 4 && client.status == 200) {
        var result = client.responseText.split("\n");
        // custom handling for the data set..
        if (result[0].search(',') !== -1) {
          result = arrCSVtoObj(result);
        }
        resolve(result);
      }
    };
    client.send();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran the script ten times on [this `names.txt`](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Be2pNwR8) (3580 lines, 29.6 KiB) and [this `data.txt`](https://www.mediafire.com/?uuyr0etye5lf3lg) (500k lines, 8.3 MiB). `names.txt` contains about 300 duplicated names, and about 2000 unused last names. About 70% of the last names in `data.txt` do not have a corresponding entry in `names.txt`.

Your code ran in `832.7 ms` on average over ten trials.

I made the following changes in arrCSVtoObj:

- Don't check `obj.hasOwnProperty` when incrementing. Saved `71.1 ms`.
- Match against a precompiled regexp. Saved `320.9 ms`.

This gave me a final speed of `440.7 ms`, making for savings of 47%! I also tried filtering out duplicates beforehand, but for this case, it actually slowed it down to `486.9 ms`.

(Edit: As @megawac asked, [here's a jsperf](http://jsperf.com/cr-se-q56941). I also included [one with smaller test cases](http://jsperf.com/cr-se-q56941/2); you'll notice that the relative difference in speed is much less.)

Here's the final function. You may notice that I explicitly specified the base in the `parseInt`; this is just in case the data file contains something like `John Doe,011`, where the `011` would parse to `9`.

```
function arrCSVtoObj(csvArr) {
    var obj = {};
    var delims = / (.+),(.+)/;

    for (var i = 0; i < csvArr.length; i++) {
        // our match may fail (empty line); just silently ignore.
        var split = csvArr[i].match(delims);
        if (!split) continue;

        var key = split[1];
        var val = parseInt(split[2], 10);

        obj[key] = val + (obj[key] || 0);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Combine this with @megawac's answer and you should notice huge savings.

Comment: How were you benchmarking. Could you create a jsperf? Is the last name `valueOf` or `toString` (etc) a valid last name?

Comment: Also skimming, it would be `obj[key] = val + obj[key] || val;
`. However if `val` can be negative this might be trouble. Maybe `if (typeof object[key] == "number") /*  ... */` would be better.... Perhaps `(object[key] || 0) + val` would work too

Comment: @megawac I actually just forgot operator precedence, haha. Added the parentheses. As for benchmarking, I just added a callback in the `processData` function and used `performance.now()` rather than `console.time()`. I don't see the value in adding that here. I guess I could write a jsperf.

Comment: thanks for the awesome input, both of you! this has definitely sped performance up. What would be a good way to make this code still workable in Safari and IE (which don't support Promises)?

Comment: @user49060 You'll want to tag megawac so he gets a notification. I got one automatically because you commented on my post.

Comment: @megawac (tag).

Comment: @user49060 you can try a promise shim https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise